# where are MyPhoneExplorer SyncJobs stored?

Tags: applications, sync

I like to know where exactly the **FileSync jobs** are stored in a MyPhoneExplorer phone profile? (in what file, and which location (profile folder or AppData folder))?

I like to **emigrate to a new phone** and I have a lot of **customized FileSync folders** configured, all the folders have the same path on my new phone and I want the same folders and options as in the old phone. How can I easily **import them into a new profile** I created for my new phone? Without creating them all over again (would spare me a lot of work).

I searched all the config files in my old phone profile folder and hoped they were stored in "FileSync.dat", I copied that file to the new profile and restarted MyPhoneExplorer, but it did not seem to work, still no SyncJobs in the SyncFiles menu...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: no, this is just the path to my profile, I'm looking for a file that keeps the sync jobs

Comment: no sync jobs are user defined (cusom) folders to sync between phone and computer hdd following a chosen sync algorithm. for example: "InternalSD/DCIM/Screenshots" to "e:\Phone\Screenshots" mode: "upload and delete original".

Comment: maybe your question is better placed in MyPhoneExplorer [Supportforum](https://fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32935)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SyncJobs are stored in "settings.dat" !
An editable text file you can open with any text editor:

- close MyPhoneExplorer
- open settings.dat from your old profile folder
- copy all the text from the rule: [FileSync_*] until the end of the file
- from the old_phone's: settings.dat
- to the new phone profile: settings.dat (in your new profile folder)
- restart MyPhoneExplorer

thanks to "Koelner" to give me this great information, that saves my day!
So I share it here and hope there will be an import/export function in the future.

[answer on MyPhoneExplorer support forum](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?p=145121#145121)